# Display JavaScript Object in a treeview

Tags: javascript, treeview

Is there any tree view component support display any arbitrary JavaScript object like:

```
{
   foo: 'bar'
   zee: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Which result in the following view:

```
/----foo 
  |   |
  |   |-- 'bar'
  |
  |--zee
      |
      |--
        |--1
        |--2
        |--3
```

Note the above ascii tree is just for demonstration of the tree structure, not necessarily the final result.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const Tree=(o,m=o,v='')=>{
    for(e in o){
        if(typeof o!=='object'){console.log(v+'┗╸'+o);return}
        Array.isArray(o)?!Array.isArray(o[e])?console.log(v+(o.length===1||o[e]===o[o.length-1]?'┗╸':'┣╸')+o[e]):Tree(o[e],m,v+(o.length===1||o[e]===o[o.length-1]?' '.repeat(o[e].toString.length+1):'┃'+' '.repeat(e.length))):(console.log(v+(e===Object.keys(m)[0]?'┏╸':Object.keys(o).length===1||Object.keys(o)[Object.keys(o).length-1]===e?'┗╸':'┣╸')+e),Tree(typeof o[e]!=='object'?String(o[e]):o[e],m,v+(Object.keys(o).length===1||Object.keys(o)[Object.keys(o).length-1]===e?' '.repeat(e.length+1):'┃'+' '.repeat(e.length))))
    }
}
//Usage : Tree(YourObjHere)

//Example :
  Tree({
     foo: 'bar',
     zee: [1, 2, 3]
  }) 

//Let me know if bugs
```

Answer (score 1):

A very good tree view component package to create a tree structure as exactly you require in the following link.
So Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/treeify

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear as to your exact need but this might suit you well: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

Comment: This doesn't work for me. coz I want to create a tree to show the structure of any arbitrary object, like what you got in chrome's console when you have `console.log(myObj)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a small library that will display JSON like you want.  JSON is pretty much a Javascript object so it should work for you needs (worked for mine).

https://github.com/lmenezes/json-tree